# Working Angular2 in vs2015 solution?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

Can anybody point me to a working angular2 in visual studio 2015. Typescript compiler throws an error "@angular/Core" module not found and all the modules.

Comment: the link provided below by @Sanket is still a great source to get you started. you have to little information on your post to fix this issue. perhaps post some code, or screen shot the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no @angular2/Core package.

If you are using latest version of angular2 then it should be **@angular/core**

You can refer this article for setting up the QuickStart files with an ASP.NET 4.x project in Visual Studio 2015 - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Comment: that's a typo error , even with "@angular/core" typescript compiler in visual studio does not recognize the modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following repo:

https://github.com/ajtowf/aspnetcore-angular2-seed

It is for Angular RC1 though, so you might have to update this manually.

If you are looking at standard MVC, you can checkout:

https://github.com/amilsil/angualr2mvc